# Strip out certain elements of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing

I need to strip out certain elements of a string.

The string(s) look a little like this:

```
var htmlelement = '<b>Frame</b>: KHAKI TORT / MATTE BLACK<br>
<b>Lens</b>: <span class="titlecaps">SMOKE MONO</span><br>
<b>Protection</b>:  Category 3 lens - Maximum UV protection
<div><b>Hardware</b>: Initial temple badge<br>
<b>Packaging</b>: Le Specs protective pouch included<br>
<b>Gender</b>: Men

  <div><b>Model</b>: 1202055<br>
<b>Warranty</b>: Le Specs are warranted for one year against manufacturing faults from the date of purchase.<br>
<br>
<hr style="border:dotted #DDD; border-width:1px 0 0 0; height:0;line-height:0px;font-size:0;margin:0;padding:10px;">
<span style="font-family:times new roman;"><span style="font-weight:bold">DESIGNER NOTES</span><br>
<br>
This oversize and tough wayfarer style in khaki tortoiseshell features a contrast black top bar.
</span>
</div>
</div>'
```

as I've converted them from HTML elements.

What I need to strip out is the Lens and frame, so for the above string, I need to return this:

```
Frame: KHAKI TORT / MATTE BLACK
Lens: SMOKE MONO
```

---

To up the problems, the string may not always be exactly as presented, for example the initial string may look like this (in a different order):

```
<b>Model</b>: 1202080<br>
<b>Protection</b>:  Category 3 lens - Maximum UV protection
<div><b>Hardware</b><span>:</span><b>&nbsp;</b><span>Silver logo temple badge</span><br>
<b>Packaging</b>: Le Specs protective pouch included<br>
<b>Gender</b>: Women<br>
<b>Warranty</b>: Le Specs are warranted for one year against manufacturing faults from the date of purchase.<br>
<br>
<b>Frame</b>: <span style="titlecaps">BLACK PRINT</span><br>
<hr style="border:dotted #DDD; border-width:1px 0 0 0; height:0;line-height:0px;font-size:0;margin:0;padding:10px;">
<b>Lens</b>: <span class="titlecaps">SMOKE GRAD</span><br>
<span style="font-family:times new roman;"><span style="font-weight:bold">DESIGNER NOTES</span><br>
<br>
Bold and glamorous, this oversize square style features soft curves featuring signature Le Specs Aztec print.
</span>
</div>
```

and I still need to simply return this:

```
Frame: BLACK PRINT
Lens: SMOKE GRAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I would take are as follows:

1. Find the index of the substring `<b>Frame</b>:`
2. Find the index of the next `<br>`
3. Cut out a substring from the first index to the second index plus 4 (the length of `<br>`)
4. Strip the html tags using regex
5. Repeat process for the second line (Lens)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using what Wes C suggested,

here's how it looked when I finished up:

```
$.each($(".descholder"), function(){
      var originalVal = $(this).html();
      var firstVal = originalVal.indexOf("Frame");
      var secondVal = originalVal.indexOf("<br>");
      var lensResult = originalVal.substring(firstVal, secondVal);
      var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
      var body = lensResult;
      var result = body.replace(regex, "");
      result = result.replace("Frame: ", '');
      $(this).parent('.descresult').html(result);
});
```